# InteractiveBrokers: Cash Balance

Tags: interactive-brokers

I started a Cash account at IKBR, transferred USD and made some trades in various currencies. When I ask "IBot" about the Cash Balance, the balance is negative and changes frequently.

On my currency statement, USD is positive, EUR, GBP are negative.

Their help states that the earnings in other currencies will stay in that currency, but why is the currency and cash balance negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IBKR's Standalone Trader WorkStation, open the Account Window.  Your available cash balance will be displayed under **Balances** as well as under **Market Value - Real FX Balance**.  It will also be shown on your daily statements.

I am not familiar with "IBot" on IBKR.

Comment: Thanks. I can see Cash EUR and Cash GBP, both negative, while Cash USD is positive. My ExLiq is negative as well though, while the Buy Pwr is 0. I wonder if I need to do any of the conversions manually.

Comment: I can't help you beyond what I suggested because I am not familiar with currency trades.  Perhaps you should contact IBKR?

Comment: Probably. They'll probably tell me this is a trading issue and they can't give advice, like they usually do. :( Thank you!

Comment: Issue is resolved. If you have negative currency positions, they charge interest on those. IBKR doesn't convert currency automatically. So the solution was to trade USD for EUR etc. and balance all currencies.